# Getting Google Maps Lat and Long coordinates

Tags: java, google-maps, maps, accessor

I'm using the following code to get the coordinates of my Google maps marker as it's position is changed

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
        lat = Math.round(marker.position.Ma * 1000) / 1000;
        lng = Math.round(marker.position.Na * 1000) / 1000;
        [.. using lat and long]
    });
```

This code used to work fine. From time to time, Google changed the position variables name Ma and Na (not sure why they do so).

So I'm using the right variables to get the lat and long, or is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
lat = Math.round(1000 * marker.getPosition().lat()) / 1000;
lng = Math.round(1000 * marker.getPosition().lng()) / 1000;
```

It sounds like you're using their private variables instead of accessor methods.

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem. I knew I'm doing something wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following the drag event gives a MouseEvent object with latLng:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function(event) {
    lat = Math.round(event.latLng.lat() * 1000) / 1000;
    lng = Math.round(event.latLng.lng() * 1000) / 1000;
    [.. using lat and long]
});
```

Comment: Just think it would be a better idea to access the event object rather than the marker itself